# keep getting error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' when i have requests installed

Tags: python, django, import, python-requests

i have python installed but i keep seeing the below error when i try to import requests.

```
  File "/x/y/z/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

here is what my code looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import requests

def say_hello(request):
    return render(requests, 'hello.html')
```

apologies in advance if this is a dumb question, i have just started to learn django.

Comment: Have you installed the `requests` package? You can do it with `pip install requests` https://pypi.org/project/pip/

Comment: What exactly do you think this `return render(requests, 'hello.html')` should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand what request does here. The `render` function requires a `request` object which is already being passed down from your function parameters. So instead of trying to call an unrelated library, you should be using the request object that you are passing through your function parameter to the `render` function. Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def say_hello(request):   # You pass this request object to the render function
    return render(request, 'hello.html')
```